# Performance testing tool for AngularJs with .net and Sql server application

Tags: .net, angularjs, performance-testing, database-performance

I have a web application (build with AngularJs, Devextreme , .net and SQLServer 2014).

I need to do performance testing for it:
1.Check application performance with huge data : 1,00,000 record in data grid
2. Application performance for more than 100 concurrent users

Looking for best approach and tool to accomplish it. Friends please give your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have anything on you mind consider [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) as it's:

- free and open source
- doesn't require any additional learning, you don't need to know extra programming language, the tests can be created using GUI
- supports HTTP and HTTPS protocols via [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
- can be configured to behave like a real browser as it supports:

  - [cookies](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
  - [headers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
  - [cache](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
- supports [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests simulation via [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)
- can talk directly to the database using [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler, you can use it for test data generation or assertions